# $H < G $, if H is normal, then $H=gHg^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this solved exercise in my lecture notes

**Let $G$ be a group and $H < G $, $\forall g \in G$ we define the conjugated subgroup with rispect to g as $gHg^{-1}$.  Verify that if H is normal, then $H=gHg^{-1}$**

If $H \triangleleft G$, by the normality criterion for each $\gamma \in  G$ and $h \in H$ we have  $\gamma h\gamma^{−1} \in H $, so
$\gamma h\gamma^{−1}  \subseteq H$.

Taking $ \gamma = g$ and $ \gamma = g^{−1}$ we get $ghg^{−1} \in H$ and $g^{−1}hg \in H$ respectively

In the first case we deduce that $gHg^{−1} ⊇ H$   ----> (1)?

and in the second case that $g^{−1}Hg ⊇ H$, that is $H ⊇ gHg^{−1}$.--->(2)?

In
conclusion, $H = gHg^{−1}$

**Can someone explain what is going on on (1) and (2) and tell if there is an error in this solution?.**

To prove (1)  they started witht $h\in H$, but I am not seeing they end with $h \in gHg^{-1}$.

In (2) they should start with a $ ghg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$ and end with $ ghg^{-1} \in H$ .

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I don't think this is a duplicate. The aim of my question is to know if there is an error in this specific solution

Comment: Did you already compare it with the standard solution?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Yes, I understand the standard solution, is the same I had done myself. I just got this solution in my lecture notes wanted to understand the solver's logic, looks to me that there is an error but I am not completely sure

Comment: We deduce $gHg^{−1} \supseteq H$ and $gHg^{−1} \subseteq H$, as in the standard solution. Can you be more precise about the "error"?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde The thing is how are they doing it here, and in (2), it doesn't seem correct or obvious to invert the inclusion

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate why it follows, though. Maybe the duplicate is more detailed, and that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $H$ is normal in $G$, then $gH=Hg$ for each $g\in G$.

Thus $gHg^{-1} = (gH)g^{-1} = (Hg)g^{-1} = H(gg^{-1}) = H$.

Comment: Thanks, I though that too, which is simpler. but my aim was to  understand the double inclusion method or to tell if there is an error in the given solution